# Android WebView not loading local HTML files

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I'm using the standard Android SDK with Ecliple as provided from the Android website.

What I want to to is to have an activity display a WebView that loads a local HTML-file. Everything works fine until I try to load the webview.

I've placed all the index-files I've tried in the project's assets-folder.

This is the code in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/index.html");
    setContentView(webView);
}
```

When I run the app over ADB, I get the following message in the WebView:

**Webpage not available**
The webpage at file:///android_assets/www/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

I know this problem has been posted before, and I've tried every single solution out there. But it just won't load. It displays online http-addresses just fine, but it doesn't seem to find any of the local files.

Please help me, this drives me mad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/index.html");
```

to this :

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

is **android_asset** not **android_assets** :D. Good Luck

Comment: Oh my. That is humiliating. Thanks a lot!

Comment: but what if I have named my asset folder `assets` ? than the url should be `file:///android_assets/index.html`

But for me it doesn't make sense, why my folder is named 'assets' and I have to write 'android_assets'.